# JWT Security Token after decoding the header and payload giving the subject in the decoded format.How to decode it?

Tags: jwt

I have a JwtSecurityToken this

```
eyJraWQiOiI1RTE1eEZ6ZFY1cUdRMHhFWTRYbzRIMUh3UTNfaWkxNlFJTFpwYVdxdE5rIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJzdWIiOiIwMHVmYXB5eXk5YWVhb1hMODBoNyIsInZlciI6MSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYtMTQ2MjQwLm9rdGFwcmV2aWV3LmNvbS9vYXV0aDIvZGVmYXVsdCIsImF1ZCI6IjBvYWVjZ28zbGZEZnNXNVlYMGg3IiwiaWF0IjoxNTI4NTMzNjk5LCJleHAiOjE1Mjg1MzcyOTksImp0aSI6IklELmhUbnZ5UndGZ2FhTVlDc2s2UXI2Ump3SVEwb0ZLZzNKYm5ENC1PWTlOS2ciLCJhbXIiOlsicHdkIl0sImlkcCI6IjAwb2VkMnZzanhDN3BuWnVsMGg3IiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTI4NTMxODc2LCJhdF9oYXNoIjoiUjNRTHdoWXhGdjNSVFZOeFZ3UXhSQSJ9.DPvrnG48Ke33w4Q_9tLtUfPWFoGGihFpWAd-GaYrVbRMBrGUZT2Rn6XUERlc03ux3OGr-JkuJ6j1SKkGVVjaJ2El09y0fxi6Is8bIMKyqCh9ldnqLn_FHYQcZWHyRmW8AQ5Awzj7sHK54NL6SttJB-Pp09J94qgTvscMcGPV-sfmkagB--0NLhxfq1wRt-hN91qqeimdpxLC-1gTgoz_VcogYEhYBiIy7S4DhjpyQ5JxVIVV2GgQ6BIq0q6vwfWf8_Lm5mxt99qIs99wdF6p6Q-dqk7GrPWxkbyO24CYXe44V6GgLm25MgQ1aA0E3LuGlasWUt9kHpJwQeLFe4LM1g
```

After decoding the JWTSecurityToken header and payload I am getting 
the header like this:-

{
  "kid": "5E15xFzdV5qGQ0xEY4Xo4H1HwQ3_ii16QILZpaWqtNk",
  "alg": "RS256"
}

and the payload like this

{
  "sub": "00ufapyyy9aeaoXL80h7",
  "ver": 1,
  "iss": "https://dev-146240.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default",
  "aud": "0oaecgo3lfDfsW5YX0h7",
  "iat": 1528533699,
  "exp": 1528537299,
  "jti": "ID.hTnvyRwFgaaMYCsk6Qr6RjwIQ0oFKg3JbnD4-OY9NKg",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "idp": "00oed2vsjxC7pnZul0h7",
  "auth_time": 1528531876,
  "at_hash": "R3QLwhYxFv3RTVNxVwQxRA"
}

But here in payload the "sub" should be my emailId but it is coming in some encoded format.I am not able to figure out how to decode it.
Please help.

Comment: Looks like an ID Token from the OIDC. The sub refers to the user ID but not necessarily the email. Maybe you don't have to decode anything here but ask specifically for the email

Comment: Thanks @Florent How to ask specifiaclly for the email.I am doing it using C#.